# Group changes in AD not reflecting for account used IIS Application Pool without rebooting

Tags: active-directory, iis

Not sure if I should ask here or at SO, but here is my issue - I have a service account which we use for IIS application pools. I recently added them to few of the AD groups and the new groups were not reflecting for the ID. For normal users, we would request them to log off and login again, so I tried the following:

1. Restart the application pool
2. Restart the IIS
3. Logoff and login my local account (I know this will have no effect,
   but tried just in case)

After playing around for a while, we rebooted the server and Voila! the permissions worked as expected. It was fine this time, but I donot want to do this on the production server.

**Is there anyway to force the account to pull in the updates from AD ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not check for iis, but should work:

1. Download and unpack [Sysinternals LogonSessions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/logonsessions.aspx)
2. Run `logonsessions.exe -p` in administrative priveleged command prompt
3. The output of this command must be found logon session id for you service account session. (Something like `00000000:00009ff1`)
4. Run `klist -li 0x<logonid>` where  in this example **9ff1**. Check that tickets exists
5. Run `klist -li 0x<logonid> purge` this will clear the tickets for the selected session
6. You may need to restart application pool or iis, 
   but it may not be necessary.

P.S. But still I do not recommend to frequently change group memberships for a service account productive server.

Comment: Wow, it worked! I didn't realize that the session wasn't getting logged off even after recycling app pools and IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **IISRESET** should re-authenticate the service account of the app pool.

I recently realized that if I changed the password of a service account running an app pool, I could recycle the app pool, stop it, start it back, stop IIS server using the GUI, start it back and the old credentials are still working for that service account. I expected it would stop working and require to enter the new credentials to use for the app pool.

However, as you said, a restart requires to re-enter the new credentials for the desired app pool.

That being said, another solution which worked was to use IISRESET command. It forced us to enter the new credentials and I am pretty sure it would also refresh the group membership in your case.

So it looks like somehow IIS is keeping the security token active even if we 
restart/stop/start the app pool.

This reading was enlightening: https://fullsocrates.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/iisreset-vs-recycling-application-pools/

Maybe it is handled by http.sys and only an IISRESET would re-authenticate the service account? I have not been able to find the real exact cause of this behavior, but your issue and the current answer confirm the behavior I also experienced.